# CodeIgniter - Live site only loads index method for default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been developing a CodeIgniter app in XAMPP on Windows 7.
The app functions as expected locally but when uploaded it doesn't.

The default controller (ShowStadium) has the following methods:
- index()
- show()

index is loaded fine when called via the basepath, but neither loads when called directly:

/pathToApp/ShowStadium/ or /pathToApp/ShowStadium/index or pathToApp/ShowStadium/show

### **The error received is the Codeigniter 404 message.**

The codeigniter instance is currently located in 2 subfolders.
My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /proj/groundtweet/

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Things I have tried:

- The controller files are all lower case.
- The base path is correct both installations.
- Tried the various uri_protocol options
- index.php has been removed from the path.

Any help would be appreciated, because I can't find an answer to this problem specifically and it's frustrating in it's probable simplicity.

Apologies if I've missed any details here.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` even parsed? What if you put `foobar` there and put it as a first line - do you get 500 error on request?

Comment: @zerkms just tried this and it does cause a 500, so the .htaccess is being parsed.

Comment: Make sure the "controllers" folder is created/visible regardless of usage

Comment: Permissions for the controllers folder is 755.

Comment: Try including `index.php/index` when accessing your function. If it works, you definitely have a problem with your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, in the end it was a matter of case sensitivity.

The controller filename was lowercase (showstadium.php) but referred to in form actions in Pascal case (ShowStadium).

It seems that for the default controller/action, CodeIgniter works around this (I haven't had a look at the guts, so I'm just making an assumption here) but when called directly the filename must match the url case - on the linux server.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code, paste this in .htaccess file. place this file under the project folder
if your project folder is groundtweet. paste the file under this folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proj/groundtweet/index.php/$1 [L]
```

i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Go to application/config/config.php and change the

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

with the one of the following options (they are commented over this config):

```
 'PATH_INFO'        Uses the PATH_INFO
 'QUERY_STRING' Uses the QUERY_STRING
 'REQUEST_URI'      Uses the REQUEST_URI
 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'   Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```

one of these should work fine for you